# In "Air", who is Richard, and what happens to him?

Tags: character, air-2023

In *Air* (2023), the story of Michael Jordan's signing with Nike, there is a very minor recurring character that has enough airtime; I would think he should be more significant. I can't understand why he's in the film, given his scenes.

Here are all of his appearances.

First, after the initial meeting where the team is trying to determine who they can sign to a shoe deal, Sonny and Strasser are talking in the men's room. As they leave, Strasser is approached for the first time by Richard, who introduces himself:

> They are interrupted at the men’s room door by RICHARD, who screams
> middle management. Beige green button up with khakis.
>
> RICHARD Mr. Strasser...
>
> Richard.
>
> Strasser has no idea who this is.
>
> STRASSER Right. Richard.
>
> RICHARD I’d love to get some time on your calendar.
>
> STRASSER Great, let Doreen know.
>
> RICHARD Roger that. Will do.
>
> STRASSER Okay.
>
> Awkward exchange of smiles. Strasser and Sonny emerge into the hallway and cross through a courtyard that passed for “people friendly break space” in 1984--populated now by overweight employees smoking cigarettes.
>
> STRASSER (CONT’D) You know there was a time I could name everyone who worked here?

Later, Sonny seeks urgently to speak to Strasser about how he knows Jordan is special. He breaks into Strasser's office, interrupting a meeting between him and Richard.

> INT. STRASSER’S OFFICE - DAY 22. 14 Framed pictures of him with NBA players, standing with his son at the Finals, the Olympics, etc. Strasser sits across from RICHARD, the guy from the men’s room.
>
> STRASSER You could look at it as shrinkage, in the budgetary sense. But I think Phil would say it’s an opportunity to expand--
>
> The door opens. Sonny pokes his head through.
>
> STRASSER (CONT’D) I’ll be done in five.
>
> SONNY I need you done now.
>
> STRASSER Sonny.
>
> RICHARD (getting up) No worries at all. I understand. It’s the busiest time of year.
>
> STRASSER Sorry about this. Thanks for coming, Richard. We’ll follow up.
>
> SONNY (almost shooing him out) Yeah, we’ll follow up.

We see Richard one more time. It's not a speaking scene. It happens in the 53rd minute of the movie. Strasser is coming into work, and walking across the quad of the bullpen. As he does this, Richard and another employee are walking diagonally in the other direction. Richard turns his head twice to watch Strasser, and Strasser turns his head slightly to see Richard.

Then the scene continues, where Sonny and Strasser talk about the Jordans coming to Nike.

It seems like a lot of work went into this one character, with no plot resolution for him.

Does anyone know if this is a significant employee in the history of Nike? The end titles did not mention this character.

Comment: Four lines of dialog doesn’t seem like so much work to me. Regarding plot resolution, what do you see as the tension/problem/driving goal that goes unresolved for Richard? Seems likely Richard is mainly there to expose traits of other characters.

Comment: @ToddWilcox.  If the first two appearances were the only ones, I wouldn't have thought anything of it.  But since in the last scene, Richard is eagerly looking toward Strasser, it seems like they were going somewhere with him.

Comment: If you're quoting from the screenplay, it's a good idea to mention that; https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Air-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf

Comment: Richard has no last name on both Wiki and IMDB's lists of characters.  They both merely mention him as "Richard".  As a result, I'd say there was no Richard involved.  His character was most likely in the Accounting department and just present to give credence to how important it was to sign Jordan.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Sorry to disagree, but.  The entire movie was an exercise as to how important it was to sign Jordan.  None of Richard's lines indicated anything about Jordan's signing.  And I am not sure how you glean that he was in the accounting department.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - Strasser literally mentions "shrinkage" and "budgetary" in that conversation.  Finances.  Clearly Richard isn't from IT, they're talking about money.  And considering Phil doesn't recognize him, Richard probably isn't an executive.  That leaves the Accounting department.  Yes, the movie showed how important it was to sign Jordan, but conversations about shrinkage and budgets hammers that home.